# Meaning of vulgar expression?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> "I can't believe it. My girl's left me. She's fucked of with some nextman."

I saw the sentence from [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Next%20man). I'm not sure what the phrase "fucked of" means. I looked it up, but I haven't found it defined in any dictionaries I consulted. Any ideas?

Comment: maybe a typo? like **** off?

Comment: Urban Dictionary is a not a good source for learning English. It's only useful when you need to look up for newly emerging slang expressions.

Comment: Dan, I suggest you edit the question to allow for an answer to the meaning of "fuck off", since we can be pretty sure "fuck of" is just a typo.  That way the question can be reopened.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As a verb, to "fuck off" normally means "get away", or "get out", as a forceful way to tell someone to leave.  You'll hear this often in movies and television (at least, in television programs that allow strong language).

A classic example, from Monty Python's [*Life of Brian*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hloWmE_3d2I) (1979):

> Brian:  All right, all right.  I *am* the Messiah!
>   Disciples: He is!  He is the Messiah!
>   Brian: Now, **fuck off**!!
>   Disciple:  ... How shall we fuck off, o lord?

The meaning of "fuck off" seems to have expanded over the years, so that now it can be used in the sense of "go away quickly" or "run off", e.g.

> I hear sirens!  We'd better **fuck off** before the cops arrive!

which is what it means in the context of your example

> I can't believe it. My girl's left me. She's **run off** with some **guy I don't know**.

"Fuck *of*" is not idiomatic, but it is possible that it's a colloquial/casual way to write "off" in some dialects.  I've never before heard the slang term "nextman"  either, but then I'm out of touch.  I try not to assume any slang expression is *wrong*, at least without more information.

Comment: The link in the original question leads to "Next man" on Urban Dictionary, where there are a variety of definitions; the common thread is "somebody else, whose identity doesn't really matter to this sentence."